# Click Event makes jQuery Mobile very slow on Mobile Devices - What is the easiest way to unbind Click event and add 'Tap' events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mobile, tap

I've scoured the internet for this answer and been unsuccessful.

Mobile devices are by default slower using the 'click' event because it continues to listen for other types of gestures, such as the double click, scroll, click and hold, etc.  Hence, jquery mobile is slow and unresponsive when trying to expand a collapsible list using 'Click'.  It delays about .5 second before triggering.

What is the easiest way that I can unbind 'Click' events from these elements and bind the 'tap' event to perform the SAME action?

My plan is to detect if the device is mobile, and if yes, then add the Tap event and thus making the site more responsive.

THANKS!

Comment: Need to see code to know how, and to what, the click events are attached.

Comment: Forget that. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235794/jquery-mobile-for-every-live-tap-event-should-there-be-an-equivalent-click-even) should help you.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot.  Unforuntaly, jquery.mobile.vmouse.js did not work in my project and received a 'Define is not Defined' error.  After messing around with it for a time, I decided to scrap it and do a simple fix.

I added a Tap event to give instant feedback to the user (changed font color), and allowed the click event to take its lag time and execute afterward - making it appear intentional.

I don't like the implementation but it does the trick for the meantime.

Comment: That's a pity, vmouse.js looked v.promising.