# Jquery keyup not working on Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, keyup

i didn't tested this code on iPhone but i'm sure (tested) it doesn't works on android mobiles:

```
 $('#search').live('keyup',function(key){
          if(key.which == 13){
            /*ANIMATE SEARCH*/
            _key = $(this).val();
            $("#wrapper").html("");
                $('#wrapper').hide(0).load('results.html').fadeIn(800);
                $('#search-fade').val(_key).fadeIn();
          }
      });
```

to explain better :

i have a simple

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>
```

don't know why but this code doesn't works properly on android mobile phones

any ideas?

Comment: you should try `on()` instead on `live()`, cause live() is deprecated.

Comment: I have reviewed the available information and changed my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(document).on('keyup','#search', function() {
   // code
});
```

or

```
$(document).delegate('#search', 'keyup', function() {
    // code
});
```

You can also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235794/jquery-mobile-for-every-live-tap-event-should-there-be-an-equivalent-click-even)

Comment: Should be "delegate" not "delegete", in case anyone comes across this solution.

Comment: Hm I tried this and its not working for me. Is there a better solution now?

Answer (score 5):

### My solution (working with jQuery 1.7.1):

```
$('#search').live('input paste', yourFunction)
```

### Tip:

Use `.on()` instead of `.live()`, because:

- `.on()` is faster
- `.live()` is deprecated

[jQuery 1.7+ .on() vs .live() Review](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/)

Try this:

```
$(document).on('input paste', '#search', yourFunction)
```

Comment: really not solve i still having this trouble cause input inside collapse is ok and event is binded while input in same page but not in collapse menu shows me the arrow instead of the search button in android keyboard :/