# JavaScript keypress event not raised on Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, keypress, hybrid-mobile-app

I have created a simple code to handle `keypress` event:

```
var counter = 0;        
$('input').on('keypress', function () {
    $('div').text('key pressed ' + ++counter);
});
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_myronov/YyKp4/)

But keypress event handler is not raised on mobile browser (Android 4+, WindowsPhone 7.5+).
What could be the issue?

Comment: Try @The System Restart's suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580295/jquery-keyup-not-working-on-android

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `keyup` event:

```
// JavaScript:
var counter = 0;        
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    document.querySelector('div').textContent = `key up ${++counter}`;
});

// jQuery:
var counter = 0;        
$('input').on('keyup', function () {
    $('div').text('key up ' + ++counter);
});
```

Comment: You could even much rather use oninput if you want to react to changes. But if what you're after is actual keys entered, none of these will help you on Android.

Comment: @ÍhorMé Do you have any solution for Android keyboard events?

Comment: @Mrunal Universally, you should use oninput event. I've posted the code for handling input text on all (or at least many) platforms here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript/42918806#42918806 if that's what you're after. It's formatted with 4-spaced tabs, though, while Stack has utterly crazy 8-spaced ones, though, mind that.

Answer (score 25):

I believe **keypress** is deprecated now. You can check in the [Dom Level 3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress). Using **keydown** or **keyup** should work. The spec also recommends that you should use [**beforeinput**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-beforeinput) instead of **keypress** but I'm not sure what the support of this is.

Comment: keydown does not deliver characters but key codes. Therefore, keydown is no replacement for keypress.

Comment: @Meixner This was a long time ago so I don't know if Keypress still isn't supported in Android. With this solution though the idea is you find the character from the keycode

Comment: "keypress" is still not supported with the on screen keyboard.

Comment: `keypress` still works with iphone but doesnt work with Android, where as `keydown` doesnt work for both for iphone and android

Comment: Note: `beforeinput` is supposed to cancellable but it is not on Chrome. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140803/why-is-contenteditable-beforeinput-event-not-cancelable

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's input event, like this:

```
$( 'input' ).on( 'input', function() {
    ...
} );
```

With this you can't use e.which for determining which key was pressed, but I found a nice workaround here: http://jsfiddle.net/zminic/8Lmay/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pattForZip = /[0-9]/;
  $('#id').on('keypress input', function(event) {
    if(event.type == "keypress") {
      if(pattForZip.test(event.key)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    if(event.type == 'input') {
      var bufferValue = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');
      $(this).val(bufferValue);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Please try to add a little more info for your solution. And welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some android browser are not supporting keypress event, we need use to only keydown or keyup but will get different keycodes, to avoiding different key codes use the following function to get the keycode by sending char value.

Eg:

```
function getKeyCode(str) {
  return str && str.charCodeAt(0);    
}
function keyUp(){
 var keyCode = getKeyCode("1"); 
}
```

Answer (score -6):

I think it is bad idea to use other events in place of 'keypress'.
What you need to do is just include a jQuery file into your project.
A file named jQuery.mobile.js or quite similar (ex. jQuery.ui.js) of any version can help you.

You can download it from : https://jquerymobile.com/download/