# Jquery keypress event on phone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is my script file to show a div on key press.
It works on pc:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 97) {   //a
        $('.login-box').show();
        $('#intial').hide();
    }
});
```

but it dos not work on phones as there is on input 
fields so I cannot open the keyboard.
Is there any way i could go about doing this?..
 preferably  a touch event (pattern)..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055270/javascript-keypress-event-not-raised-on-android-browser

Comment: see that post is listening to an input field   here im just listening for the a key in the window

Comment: USe the touchstart event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the `keyup` or `keydown` event.

I believe the `keypress` was deprecated and won't work in this situation.

```
$(document).on('keyup', function () {
    if(e.keyCode === 97) {   //a
        $('.login-box').show();
        $('#intial').hide();
    }
});
```