# Android Phone - Input field retaining every keypress and appending on replace

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

Aim : Disallow numeric values on an input Field

Logic: I am trying to replace every numeric value with empty string.
But on every next keypress, the original val string is prepended to it.

For example :

```
---------------------------------------------------------
Key Entered          |         Value reflected in Input
---------------------------------------------------------
A                    |                A
b                    |                Ab
1                    |                Ab
c                    |                AbAbc
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Code :

HTML

```
 <input id="charText" value="" class="alpha">
```

Script

```
$('.alpha').on('keyup', function () {

    //$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'') );
    $val = $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'');;
    $('.alpha').val($val);
    });
});
```

Works for desktop. Error only in my Android mobile

Comment: r u typing in native android application or in html page

Comment: It is a basic test html page

Comment: Have you tried other events like ``onchange`` or ``oninput``? I have found this post, it seems similiar to your problem: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/val-function-interweaving-new-value-with-old-value-on-android-s-nexus-s

Comment: the direction you gave helped me solve it..thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the same using following script
(Ref : [JavaScript keypress event not raised on Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055270/javascript-keypress-event-not-raised-on-android-browser))

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.alpha').on('keyup input', function (event) {

        if(event.type == 'input') {
          var bufferValue = $(this).val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g,'');
          $(this).val(bufferValue);
        }

    });
});
```