# why is contenteditable beforeinput event not cancelable?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

Reading [this](https://webkit.org/blog/7358/enhanced-editing-with-input-events/) webkit document, It says the beforeinput event when used with contenteditable is cancelable. But I run the code in the document on a chrome browser and the event is not cancelable.

Am I mistaken?  How to enable the beforeinput event to be cancelable?

```html
<body onload="setup()">
  <div id="editor" contenteditable>
    <p>This is some regular content.</p>
    <p>This text is fully editable.</p>
    <div class="quote" style="background-color: #EFFEFE;">
      <p>This is some quoted content.</p>
      <p>You can only change the format of this text.</p>
    </div>
    <p>This is some more regular content.</p>
    <p>This text is also fully editable.</p>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  function setup()
  {
    editor.addEventListener("beforeinput", event =>
    {
      if (event.inputType.match(/^format/))
        return;

      for (let staticRange of event.getTargetRanges())
      {
        if (nodeIsInsideQuote(staticRange.startContainer)
          || nodeIsInsideQuote(staticRange.endContainer))
        {
          event.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
      }
    });

    function nodeIsInsideQuote(node)
    {
      let currentElement = node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ? node : node.parentElement;
      while (currentElement)
      {
        if (currentElement.classList.contains("quote"))
          return true;
        currentElement = currentElement.parentElement;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I opened an issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/w3c/input-events/issues/92

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: I was so glad to find this question, and so bummed to find no answers.