# masked input working ok on desktop and working ok for some masks on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maskedinput

I am using a masked plugin for two fields. One is for a Canadian Postal Code (T5T 5T5)and the other is for a phone number (999-999-9989). Both masks work ok on desktop. The problem is seen if you open the same code on a mobile phone. As the user types in the Postal Code one, the cursor keeps jumping to the beginning of the cursor.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="someID" /> (T9T 1A1)
<br />
<span id="result"></span>
<br /><br />
<input type="text" id="someOtherID" /> (999-999-9999)
<br />
<span id="result1"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#someID").mask("a9a 9a9");
$("#someID").on('keyup', function() {
  var actualValue = $(this).val().replace(/[_-\s]/g, '').length;
  if (actualValue === 0 || actualValue !== 6) {
    $("#result").text("not valid")
  } else {
    $("#result").text("valid")
  }
});

$("#someOtherID").mask("999-999-9999");
$("#someOtherID").on('keyup', function() {
  var actualValue = $(this).val().replace(/[_-\s]/g, '').length;
  if (actualValue === 0 || actualValue !== 10) {
    $("#result1").text("not valid")
  } else {
    $("#result1").text("valid")
  }
});
```

I have attached the Mask plugin on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8zqdk0e/7/).

Anyone ever seen this?

Comment: Does the demo work on your phone? http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

Comment: Yes it does work on my phone but product key on the website does the same jumping.

Comment: Looks okay on my mobile device. What device / OS / browser are you using when experiencing the issues?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Note 5

Comment: Do you mean it keeps jumping to the **end** of the text box? It happens to me too but the cursor goes back to the correct position after a split millisecond and doesn't affect my typing. I tried it on android 4.4.4 with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @mpora Chrome? Newest version?

Comment: It jumps to the beginning of the input. So say I type T the cursor will jump to the beginning of the T

Comment: @iMoses Yes, newesest version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a longshot, but try setting the `autoComplete="off"` attribute on your input fields. It might be a bug related to Chrome for mobile.

[Try this.](https://jsfiddle.net/e8zqdk0e/9/)

My hunch is based on [this issue](https://github.com/effektif/react-mentions/issues/30) that, although reported on a completely different scenario, I believe refers to the same bug.

Quoting:

> Indeed the issue is caused by the auto-correction.
>
> When a word is marked for a suggestion, the `selectionStart` and
>   `selectionEnd` are not reflecting the caret position but they wrap the
>   whole word, even though the caret is somewhere in between and the
>   actual selection is collapsed.

My assumption is that the cursor must be manipulated in order to create the masking visual effects, so that may very well be connected.

Comment: I am back with the same issue. The fix you had given me fixed my issue but now its failing again.

Comment: Only on Chrome again?

Comment: Yes, only in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

probably because you are writing the **keyup** listener the wrong way

this post has the answer: [Jquery keyup not working on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580295/jquery-keyup-not-working-on-android)

### UPDATE

well... the mask plugin itself may be the root of this problem... a quick look at the source code reveals:

```
            el.on('input.mask keyup.mask', p.behaviour)
            .on('paste.mask drop.mask', function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    el.keydown().keyup();
                }, 100);
            })
```

so i guess that you may try to eliminate a suspicios code for mobile devices until you reach the desireable effect

Comment: Tried this but it is not working. The cursor still jumps to the beginning.