# Auto Tap on Mobile on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm using codes below to auto click an id on page load. It works on desktop but not on mobile. How to auto "tap" the id on mobile?

```
<div id="media"></div>    

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#media').click(function() {
    alert('tap!');
  });   

  $('#media').trigger('click');

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422944/jquery-mobile-difference-betwing-click-and-tap

Answer (score 0):

You should use [vclick()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/) which virtualizes a click event (only if using jQueryMobile).