# jquery tap event radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tap event doesn't seem to work for radio buttons.

```
$(document).on("tap","input[type=radio]",function(e){//do something});
```

This event does not fire.
The click events seem to be working fine for radio buttons.

And tap events seem to be working for all other types of buttons.

**COMPLETE HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("tap","input[type=radio]",function(e){alert("tapped");});
});
</script>

<body>
<form action="#">
  <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male">Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female">Female<br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>Click on the submit button to submit the form.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The Same works fine if i replace **tap** with **click**.

**tap** events are working fine otherwise so that's not the issue.

Comment: [difference-between-the-click-and-tap-events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422944/what-is-the-difference-between-the-click-and-tap-events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is jquery mobile library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

You can check out this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_tap) from W3Schools.

Even though `tap` event is equivalent to `click` event in jquery, you need to add mobile library to make `tap` event work.

Check out this working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8m6vpqkk/) for your case.