# How to close message box (div) when click outside using html code only (can't use jquery as page only accept html code?

Tags: html, css, button

## please don't close it with "use jquery to close DIV " example. As I can only use HTML code on my page.

> can anyone help me to find the code which close DIV (message box) when clicked outside. > > And these current 4 buttons are not aligned in the same line > is there any code to align the buttons in one line as well Thanks
>
> ```css
> .alert {
>  display: none;
>  padding: 20px;
>  background-color: #f44336;
>  color: white;
> }
>
> .closebtn {
>  margin-left: 15px;
>  color: white;
>  font-weight: bold;
>  float: right;
>  font-size: 22px;
>  line-height: 20px;
>  cursor: pointer;
>  transition: 0.3s;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <button onclick="document.getElementById('alert1').style.display='block'">Button1</button> <div id="alert1" class="alert"> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>Message 1 </div>
>
> <button onclick="document.getElementById('alert2').style.display='block'">Button2</button> <div id="alert2" class="alert"> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>Message 2 </div>
>
> <button onclick="document.getElementById('alert3').style.display='block'">Button3</button> <div id="alert3" class="alert"> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>Message 3 </div>
>
> <button onclick="document.getElementById('alert4').style.display='block'">Button4</button> <div id="alert4" class="alert"> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>Message 4 </div>
> ```

Comment: Simply add `onblur = "document.getElementById('alert1').style.display='none'"` to button 1 (and also the other buttons using 2,3,4)... Does not look very nice, certainly not the preferred use, but that is what u asked for.

Comment: If you want the buttons to align, you need to put the buttons separate from the alerts inside a `div` and the alerts inside another. The way you constructed it now won't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty (especially **dirty**) solution for both your questions is as follows:

1) put the "alerts" in a separate `div` below the `button`s to keep them aligned

2) add `onblur = "document.getElementById('alertxxxxxx').style.display='none'"`

to you `button` elements.

```css
.alert {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert1').style.display='block'" onblur="document.getElementById('alert1').style.display='none'">Button1</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert2').style.display='block'" onblur="document.getElementById('alert2').style.display='none'">Button2</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert3').style.display='block'" onblur="document.getElementById('alert3').style.display='none'">Button3</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('alert4').style.display='block'" onblur="document.getElementById('alert4').style.display='none'">Button4</button>
<div>
  <div id="alert1" class="alert"> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>Message 1 </div>
  <div id="alert2" class="alert"> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>Message 2 </div>
  <div id="alert3" class="alert"> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>Message 3 </div>
  <div id="alert4" class="alert"> <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>Message 4 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is aligned now , However on my page it is not closing automatically when we click outside ( so the mouse click works) but when use it on touch screen phone it does not close when touch tap outside. Also when tap on multiple buttons it opens the alert for all of the buttons clicked. Is there anything you can recommend. Or do you know what is causing this issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: The stacking of the alert windows is caused by the way you constructed the code. As you wanted a 'html-only' that is a side effect. It would be better to create javascript inside the doc and attach some `eventListener` to the buttons. 'clicks' are indeed not 'taps'. Need to dig into that subject, maybe it is another 'on...=' that needs to be used instead of 'onclick'.

Comment: Can you please advise or add any another way of coding it. Will be really appreciated

Comment: Create a `<script>....</script>` in your document and you can do all the programming you want. Further read [What is the difference between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422944/). Need to create something like that in your doc. There is no easy way....

Comment: will try with <script> tag cheers > but the earlier coding you provided fixed 99% of my problem cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately there are little shortcuts in learning to develop software. When I see some interesting behaviour on sites I visit, I frequently have a look at the source. Furthermore, [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) has a large user base with many,many short examples of HTML/CSS/JS created by the community, well worth your time. [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) likewise. You can spend weeks on those two without doing any coding yourself... Success!